# Iterate through directories and compare two images [MATLAB]

Tags: image, matlab, loops, directory

I want to compute the image quality metric VIF with MATLAB. Therefore I downloaded `vifp_mscale.m`. Now I could use the function `vif = vifvec(img1, img2)`. But I have two directories (including subdirectories) where I have a bunch of images. How can I loop through these folders and compare the images properly?

Answer (score -1):

Use [`dir`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html):

```
ImageFolder1 = dir([pwd '/subfolder1/*.png']) % Or whatever file extension
ImageFolder2 = dir([pwd '/subfolder2/*.png'])
```

Now you can loop over the contents of the structures `ImageFolder1` and `ImageFolder2`.

Comment: Thank you!
Something like that:

for k = 1:length(ImageFolder1)
  img1 = ImageFolder1(k);

is this the right way?

Comment: @JoeyDoey more or less. Take a good look at what the structure actually contains, you can't call it quite that way. You do loop over all things contained in the `ImageFolder`, but you still have to load each image into your workspace. I'm not going to spell everything out for you though, as you have not provided your own attempt in code.

Comment: `vifp_mscale;

ImageFolder1 = dir([pwd 'path_to_directory\*.png']);
ImageFolder2 = dir([pwd 'path_to_directory\*.png']);

for k = 1:length(ImageFolder1)
    img1 = load(ImageFolder1(k).name);
    img2 = load(ImageFolder2(k).name);
    
    vif = vifvec(img1, img2);
end`

is this right?

Comment: @JoeyDoey looks about right, yes. You might need to modify the `load([pwd ImageFolder2(k).name])` though, as I am unsure whether `load` can find files in subfolders without specifying the full path. I take it you tried the code and already know whether it works?